# How to prevent flexible widgets from truncating too early?

Tags: flutter

With the following code I get a screen that looks as follows, which as you can see there is plenty of room for the text:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '5/23/2023',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 6,
                  ),
              maxLines: 1,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                'Some amount of letters',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 6,
                    ),
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: without flexible]

However, if I wrap the first `Text` widget in a `Flexible` widget, I get the following behavior:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                '5/23/2023',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 6,
                    ),
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                'Some amount of letters',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 6,
                    ),
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: without flexible]

I suspect the premature truncation of the word 'letters' is due to an equal amount of space being allocated to both the `Flexible` and `Expanded` widgets due to there not being a flex factor supplied (each defaults to 1). However, my desired outcome is to allow the first text element to be as big as it wants within a single line (and truncate with an ellipsis if it becomes too long), and then allocate all remaining space on the line to the second text element, which will also truncate with an ellipsis if there is not enough room.

As it stands, the best I can do is omit the first `Flexible` widget as in the first example and hope that the text never grows to a point where it flows off screen, causing an overflow exception. I haven't found a combination of Flexible/Expanded that achieves this, and supplying flex factors is essentially guessing how big content should be and inevitably leads to inflexibility in the design if the content is too long or short.

Is this an impossible requirement based on how Flutter's layout works?